# Resolve stopped working after migrating to Angular 10+

Tags: angular, resolve

The following resolve method used to work till Angular 9, and it stopped working after upgrading to Angular 10+

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: ServicesModule,
})
export class SampleResolverService implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  resolve(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable<any>((observer) => {
      this.someService.makeACall().subscribe((value) => {
        this.store.dispatch(SomeAction.updateStore({value}));
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

after upgrading to Angular 10+, even though the resolve function is working, but the navigation is not happening, and no errors are thrown.

Does anyone know why this wouldn't work in Angular 10+, and how to achieve the same functionality in Angular10+ on wards

Thanks

Comment: Try add the type to the "observer" and "value": `new Observable<any>((observer:any)=>...` and `.subscribe((value:any)=>...` BTW Are you sure about your code `this.store.dispatch(SomeAction.updateStore({value}))`? should be or `this.store.dispatch(SomeAction.updateStore({...value}))` -using the spread operator- or `this.store.dispatch(SomeAction.updateStore(value))` -pass the "value".

Comment: @Eliseo the dispatching actions in my code is just a sample one; I've updated the question now; after the upgrade, the navigation stopped working, that is the issue I am trying to fix